# Getting PHP 7.2 on mac using AMPPS

Tags: php, macos, ampps

I've been using AMPPS for my local dev environment on Mac OS X for years but I need PHP 7.2 for my latest project. My question is two-fold: is there a way yet to get PHP 7.2 with AMPPS and if not, what should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure about AMPPS, but I would always recommend having a look at Docker.  You can mix and match versions of various components as you need.

Comment: Does docker work as a web server or with the web server? Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: I have also same issue. Please help.